# How do I make my Word document read-only in a SharePoint library when I'm not an owner of that library?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-permissions, read-only, access-rights

Generally, owners and members of a SharePoint group seem to be able to edit all documents in the SharePoint group's document library.

Is there a way to make a specific document in that library (here, a Word document) read-only regardless?

Comment: You have to break the permissions at document/file level & grant only read access to the users.

Comment: Thanks -- how do I do that, i.e. where can these 'permissions at document/file level' be changed?